# Template para filhos de uma categoria de post Wordpress

Tags: php, html5, wordpress

como faço pra determinar o estilo do layout dos posts filhos de uma categoria em específico?
É possível fazer isto?

Comment: Me dei conta que fala de "estilo do layout"... está falando de CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Sim, basta seguir a [Hierarquia dos Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). No seu caso, o que precisa é de um destes dois arquivos no seu tema:

- `/wp-content/themes/seu-tema/category-$slug.php`
- `/wp-content/themes/seu-tema/category-$id.php`

Por exemplo, se a categoria for "sapatos", crie o seguinte arquivo no seu theme: `/seu-tema/category-sapatos.php`.

Confira o `slug` das suas categorias em `http://example.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category`, e o ID clicando em uma das categorias na administração e conferindo a `tag_ID` na URL.

[Neste guia visual](http://wphierarchy.com/) pode-se ver como funciona a hierarquia, a prioridade é da esquerda para a direita. Primeiro procura-se pelo arquivo `category-$slug.php`, se não existir procura por `category-$id.php`, se não existir usa-se `category.php`, etc.

[image: hierarquia para category]